# Why does this Ruby code not return the expected answer?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying the list all factors of a number using the following method:

```
def find_factors(n)
  factors = []
  2.upto(n-1) {|x| factors << x if n % x == 0}
end

factor = find_factors(24)
puts factor
```

Its printing out the following:

```
2
```

instead of the list of factors! What am if doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`upto` used with a block returns the receiver, which is `2`.

A better way to write this would be:

```
def find_factors(n)
  2.upto(n-1).select{|x| (n % x).zero?}
end
```

Comment: Better as in more elegant/idiomatic, or faster?

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, whenever you see an array initialization before a loop, you can generally convert it to a more functional approach:

```
def find_factors(n)
  2.upto(n-1).select{|x| n % x == 0}
end
```

This tends to be more compact and often more readable too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `factors` at the end of your `find_factors` method:

```
def find_factors(n)
  factors = []
  2.upto(n-1) {|x| factors << x if n % x == 0}
  factors
end
```

Comment: Duh! Facepalm :( Sorry for wasting the community's time!! Thanks for the quick response!